# How to make each <li> tag appear slowly one after the other

Tags: jquery

I want the list item to appear on the screen slowly one after the other when the page loads.This is the code in jquery, I have used `show()` but it is not working. I did look up for questions here some of them are using append method but that is not what I am looking for.

html:

```
 <ul>
 <li>A</li>
 <li>B</li> 
 <li>C</li> 
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$("ul").find("li").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(500*i).show();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding CSS animation with delay to each list item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165160/adding-css-animation-with-delay-to-each-list-item)

Comment: You need to first hide the li elements for this to work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d0xagqes/1/ - also need to use the version of `show()` that uses the animation queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

For this to work, first the `li` elements must be hidden, then since you are using `delay()`, you need to a version of `show()` that uses the animation queue.

```js
$("ul").find("li").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(500 * i).show(0);
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

---

Another way using classes is

```js
$("ul li.hidden").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(500 * i).queue(function(nxt) {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    nxt();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="hidden">A</li>
  <li class="hidden">B</li>
  <li class="hidden">C</li>
</ul>
```